# RSS feeds in the front page

Tags: views, feeds

How I can set which rss feeds are put at my frontpage like that

Feeds are produced by Views.

Right no feed link exists in frontpage.
What would be also the right syntax for HTML5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default frontpage view provides what you need as long you `print $feed_icons;` in your page.tpl.php

Comment: it does not print anything for me

Comment: So do you have feed_icons in your page.tpl.php?

Comment: feed_icons print probably the default drupal feed. i have made a view just with an rss display at path /rss.xml. how i can force this path to be at $feed_icons sitewide?

Comment: you have to attach this feed to a page display

Comment: sidewide you need some kind of custom code afaik

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node.module (i.e. the /node url) for your front page, that will have a feed automatically. In fact, you can turn this off if you replace the home page listing using Views. See here: http://drupal.org/node/413620#comment-2142182

Feeds will be provided by Views under certain circumstances. Firstly, you have to create a special RSS display for each feed you want to expose. Do this by creating a new view, then adding a display of type RSS and configuring that to expose the information you require. Secondly, for the RSS view to appear on the page you're concerned with, you need to configure the views path correctly. You can configure this to be the front page, if I recall correctly. You can also attach the feed display directly to a page or block display in that same part of the interface.

Comment: in order to do that I need a page display in View, and give path /node for front-page. The matter is that the front page is produced by another view, which has totally different content. My issue is: I have a view that produces an rss. I would like that feed-icon to appear site-wide. It cannot appear now except if I manually put link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" at html.tpl.php. I would like a more elegant way than writing it manually

Comment: Not sure what to tell you man! :) On my site, I have a side block with manually added links to the feeds. This ensures they're site-wide, and isn't a particularly ugly way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the default view called "frontpage" in View page and in that view, you will see "Feed" display  and edit it according to your requirement.